# Validation problems with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, warnings

I'm making practice with `CakePHP` user registration validation but I get some error from the core:

```
Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 2611]
```

This is the validation array:

```
var $validate = array (
    'username' => array (
        'ruleUser1'=> array (
            'rule' => 'alphaNumberic',
            'message' => 'The username must be alphanumeric only'
        ),
        'ruleUser2' => array (
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Username can\'t be empty'
        ),
        'ruleUser3' => array (
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array (
        'rulePass1'=> array (
            'rule' => array ('minLength', 8),
            'message' => 'Password must be 8 character length'
        ),
        'rulePass2' => array (
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Password can\'t be empty'
        )
    )
);
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Try removing fields/rules to find out which field/rule is generating error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'username' => array (
    'ruleUser1'=> array (
        'rule' => 'alphaNumberic',
        'message' => 'The username must be alphanumeric only'
    ),
```

**alphaNumberic** should be **alphaNumeric**. I think that is the source of the problem?